# EnterpriseLibrary Logging permissions error

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library

I have a website using the EnterpriseLibrary Logging Block for logging messages. It is configured and working correctly in all environments except one test environment, which generates an internal error each time the website writes a log message.

```
ProcessId: Unable to read intrinsic property. Error message: System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission
Process Name: Unable to read intrinsic property. Error message: System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission
Thread Name:
Win32 ThreadId: Unable to read intrinsic property. | Error message: Permission for UnmanagedCode is not available.

Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.LoggingHResult: -2146233078
StackTrace Information Details:
  at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl.GetLogicalOperationStack()
  at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriterImpl.<>C__DisplayClass1.<Write>b__0()
```

The website has the correct permissions for writing to the log directory/file. What missing permissions are causing the above error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EnterpriseLibrary Logging requires Full Trust within IIS. In IIS Manager, select the top level server and/or each individual website and open .NET Trust Levels in the Features View. In this case the trust level had been accidentally changed to High and changing it back to Full resolved the error.